# Cannot launch Chrome using Appium

Tags: google-chrome, appium

Cannot open Chrome using Appium (1.4.16.1) on my Android real device (6.0.1)
I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. 
(Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
(Original error: unknown error: Device abcd is not online (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845
(73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Below are my Capabilities:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "abcd");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "chrome");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

- You should set a correct `deviceName` capability. `abcd` seems like not correct. In the command line execute `adb devices` and it will show you device's name.
- Remove excess line     `capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");`
- `BROWSER_NAME` capability set to `Chrome`
- Strongly recommended upgrade to Appium 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try these,

1. Kill the node.exe process from Windows Task Manager and Restart your Appium Server.

2.Open SDK Manager and Update latest Packages based on your Device Andriod version.

also,

Reconfigure all the .jar file from Build Path -> Config Build Path -> Library - Remove and Add again all the .jars(if it is Maven then edit/save dependencies in POM.xml again). Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks but tried all of these with no success :(
I can open chrome browser now but cannot navigate to any website/click on any element. 
The browser opens up with `data;` and kills itself after 2 secs and this process repeats for 3-4 times.